# earnings potential. (potential is adjective or noun here?)

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

For each job on your list, you should do some careful research in order to learn about the occupation's educational requirements, outlook, and earnings **potential**.

'potential' is used both for an adjective and a noun.

It looks like noun. What is the part of speech of 'potential' in this sentence above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'potential' were an adjective here, it would precede 'earnings': potential earnings.

Sometimes the [postpositive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) is used, such as in 'matters financial' but that is not the case here, such use would be stilted.

So 'earnings potential' is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).